# How do I use a custom select statement in Hibernate using the HibernateDaoSupport class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am trying to write a custom select statement in Hibernate using the getHibernateTemplate() method.  I am having problems with the resulting mapping.

Example Code:

```
List<User> users = getHibernateTemplate().find("Select user, sysdate as latestPost from User as user");
for (User user : users) {
assertNotNull(users.name);
}
```

The goal of the above line is to eventually have a join where I get the max(date) of posts made by the user.  The problem I am having is that the resulting users list is not a list of User objects and I get a class cast exception.

Hopefully that is enough code.  It is a greatly simplified version of my problem and a combination of snippets from various parts of my application.

Comment: So what does the list contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out.  I am already using a HibernateDaoSupport derived DAO class so this solution goes along with that.

```
String queryString = "Select {user.*}, (select max(submitted) from posts where post.user_id = user.id) MAX_POST from users user";
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
query.addEntity("user", User.class);
query.addScalar("MAX_POST", Hibernate.DATE);

List results = query.list();
List<User> users = new ArrayList();
for (Object item : results) {
    Object[] element = (Object[]) item; 
    User user = (User)element[0];
    user.setMaxPost((Date)element[1]);
    users.add(user);
}
```

The above example is greatly simplified but should show a method you can use to solve this problem.  I actually was able to include one of my EAGER fetches by incorporating into the SQL the neccessary tables and then use the addJoin method

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Hibernate isn't want you want here.  Maybe you should start with SimpleJDBCTemplate and a RowMapper and build up from there.

Comment: Already have a pretty complex site built up.  Just have this page that shows a table of users and next to them how many posts they have, only the real problem is far more complicated than that.  I have a total of 9 aggregates I need to show and the front end is in JSF. That is another route I may just have to take.  I was just hoping to combine the data pull into 1 query instead of so many (users x 9)

Comment: Thanks, this comment did get me onto the right track as noted in the solution I posted.